# Simple code not responsive on codepen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, responsive, codepen

I'm doing a beginner's course in HTML/CSS and I'm working on a very simple project in codepen. I'm using bootstrap to make my page mobile responsive and when I reduce the window size in codepen it seems fine but when I access it on my mobile, it does not work! The page is too wide for the screen.

I commented out the vast majority of my code to pinpoint the issue and am now left with just a jumbotron and it still doesn't work.

Here's the codepen link:

https://codepen.io/dave-bage/pen/Pedemz

And the actual code is as simple as:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="jumbotron header">
    <h1 class="text-center">Chester Bennington</h1>
    <h2 class="text-center">A tribute to a true legend of rock</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

The only relevant CSS is:

```
body {
  background-color: rgb(168, 176, 191);
}

.header {
  background-color: rgb(75, 85, 102);
  color: rgb(208, 217, 232);
  margin-top: 30px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 6em;
  font-family: 'New Rocker', cursive;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Rock Salt', cursive;
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Was as simple as me making the font too large!